# EF Core 2.0 update database again, once all migrations run

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, aspnetboilerplate, ef-core-2.0

It's a simple task I think.

My requirement is to **run one .sql file after all migrations runs successfully.**
it contains few alter statements. the system is in a way that I must have to run this Sql, there are no other way like I just update my entity.

I am using asp.net zero architecture.

Right now I am updating my migrations manually and adding this query's with

```
 migrationBuilder.Sql("");
```

but it's hard to maintain.

I have done some R&D on this topic but not found anything proper.

as I am following best practice of .net boilerplate structure, I would like to hear from boilerplate dev side too.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the requirement by creating Stored Procedures or Scalar value function.

1. Create Empty Migration by running `Add-Migration` command in
   **Package Manager Console**.
2. Add the SQL query in `Up` method like the following way.

   ```
   public partial class testQuery : Migration {
       protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
       {
           migrationBuilder.Sql(@"You query");
       }
   }
   ```

Or

Add Stored Procedures folder and testSP.sql inside it. testSP.sql will have whole SP definition.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    var spPath = @"MyCompany.MyTemplate.EntityFrameworkCore\Migrations\Stored Procedures\testSP.sql";

    var spMigratorPath = Path.Combine("..", spPath);

    if (!File.Exists(spMigratorPath))
    {
        spMigratorPath = Path.Combine("..", "..", "..", "..", spPath);
    }

    migrationBuilder.Sql(File.ReadAllText(spMigratorPath));
}
```

3. Run Update-Database in Package Manager Console.

It will create the function or SP in DB.

Now You can call SP by using [ExecuteSqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx) or [ExecuteSqlCommandAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommandasync(v=vs.113).aspx) methods.

You can also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48268866/6527049).

Comment: vivek that's what I am doing now, but what if someone removes all migrations and create InitialDB, I will lost my query.

Comment: why do we need to remove migration?

Comment: because in big application, every week there are at least 50-60 migrations, and in team of more then >8 members, it's hard to maintain this kind of fixes

Comment: yes, but its developer's responsibility, not to delete them or do it carefully

Comment: this is not a question at all, what I want is generic solution, and that's why I posted my question over here..